# Is there somewhere I can download real FDR data?

Tags: flight-data-recorder, cockpit-voice-recorder

Is there any way to get FDR data via the internet? Like actual FDR data from 9/11:

https://undicisettembre.blogspot.com/2007/07/ntsb-flight-recorder-data-and.html

Answer (score 6):

The only cases I'm aware of where you can do that is when the NTSB publishes it in an accident report. Otherwise, that data is considered proprietary to the aircraft operator & isn't disclosed to the public.

Comment: In which case I've seen it reported in graph format, but not as raw data.